# How to Stop or Exit Hangfire

Tags: hangfire

Hangfire currently runs continuously from one deployment to another. Is there any way I can exit or force stop it after particular time?

I am currently using backgroundServerOptions with worker count

Comment: What do you mean by "deployment"? Hangfire is not a deployment tool, but a background worker.

Comment: You mean the [BackgroundJobServer](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/BackgroundJobServer.cs)?